# Svg map does not seem in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

My problem is that the svg based map does not seem in Firefox.
Chrome, Edge, Opera is OK, only Firefox doesn't.
The site is: http://2018.tvep.hu/tagletszam-alakulasa.html
I appreciate any help! Thanks: Laszlo Varga

Comment: There is no svg map on the logon screen ... please provide a minimal, verifiable (ie., among others, publicly accessible) example.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was password protected page, but now i unlocked.

Comment: A minimal version of the SVG that still reproduces the issue should really be included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter `inner-shadow` is invalid because the first `feComposite` references an undefined `offset-blur` as its `in2`. Firefox is, as usual and rightfully, more strict and doesn't just ignore the problematic input. Removing the `in2="offset-blur"` makes it work because it will then automatically use the result of the previous filter (from [the SVG 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterPrimitiveInAttribute)):

> If no value is provided and this is a subsequent filter primitive, then this filter primitive will use the result from the previous filter primitive as its input.

Adding `result="offset-blur"` to the `feOffset` above it would achive the same.

Comment: Thanks mmlr, by adding `result="offset-blur"` was the right solution.
Many thanks!